# Items not getting pushed to an array inside the Javascript promise

Tags: javascript, next.js, es6-promise, javascript-scope

In the following exported function which is from a Nextjs app as an API page, the `domainnames` array is returning nothing in the 200 response.

However, if I do not use the `GetDomainStatus()` function and just push items from `response.data.results` into `domainnames`, then the JSON response is filled.

```
export default function GetSuggestions(req, res){
const keyword = req.query.q;
const tlds = '.com,.net,.io,.org,.co,.xyz,.app,.us,.blog,.shop,.land,.video,.review,.host,.dev';
let queryPath = `${suggestionsURL}?include-registered=false&tlds=${tlds}&include-suggestion-type=true&sensitive-content-filter=true&use-numbers=true&max-length=20&lang=eng&max-results=100&name=${keyword}&use-idns=false`
let domainnames = [];

axios.get(queryPath).then(response => {

  response.data.results.forEach(item => {

      GetDomainStatus(item.name).then(a => {
        domainnames.push({
          name: item.name,
          avail: a
        })
      })
  })
  res.status(200).json(domainnames);
});
```

}

is this a scope issue where I actually cannot access `domainnames` array from within the promise?

Comment: yes they are - asynchronously

Comment: You need to use Promise.all() to send the res only after all GetDomainStatus() calls have finished.

Comment: @ChrisG can you provide an example, I do not fully understand. Do I need to use promise.all on each iteration through results or push a new promise in the loop?

Comment: You need to use `Promise.all(response.data.results.map(item => GetDomainStatus(item.name).then(a => ({ name: item.name, avail: a })))).then(domainnames => res.json(domainnames));`

Comment: Explanation: Promise.all() expects an array of promises and resolves to an array of the results in the same order. So you need to map your array of items to an array of promises and pass the result to Promise.all, then .then() that to send back the result array.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked. Not sure if its the best, but uses the promise.all solution.

```
const domainnames = [];
const promises = [];

axios.get(queryPath).then(response => {

  response.data.results.forEach(item => {

    let newPromise = GetDomainStatus(item.name).then(a => {
        domainnames.push({
          name: item.name,
          avail: a
        })
    });
    promises.push(newPromise);
  })
  Promise.all(promises).then(r => res.status(200).json(domainnames));

});
```